# How can I swap the order of application in a defined F# function?

Tags: f#, functional-programming

Given a general function `f:a->b->c`

I want to create the function that does the same thing/computation that f does but with the order of the two input parameters (or the currying order) swapped around.

So looking for `g:b->a->c` where `g` does the exact same computation as `f`

==

```
let transform1 (f:a->b->c) : (b->a->c) = 
?
```

Comment: I've dropped the Haskell tag from the question since it appears to be entirely  about F#, and Haskell is not even mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can actually tell from the type of the function how to do this.

`transform1` has the type `(a -> b -> c) -> (b -> a -> c)` or, equivalently, `(a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c`.

So what you're looking for is a function that takes

- a function `a -> b -> c` which we'll call `f`,
- and a `b`,
- and an `a`,
- and then "uses" `f` with the `a` and the `b` in order to produce a `c`.

Since there's only one way to "use" `f` with the `a` and the `b` that produces a `c` you write that way down:

```
flip f b a = f a b
```

and that's it.

Answer (score 6):

You can define a `swap` function thus:

```
let swap f a b = f b a
```

Answer (score 2):

In Haskell you'd do that like this:

```
g b a = f a b -- or using lambda expressions: (\b a -> f a b)
```

So in a `let` statement: `let g = (\b a -> f a b) in ...`

Comment: I think the author meant that he wanted to take function `f` as parameter and return the flipped version.

Comment: That's basically "return the lambda wrapper around `f` like I posted"?

Comment: ya, pretty much abstract over `f`, so `(\f a b -> f b a)`

Comment: The [flip](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:flip) function is part of the Prelude. Why not `let g = flip f in ...`?

Comment: the question was about F#, where `flip` is *not* part of the lib